# Way to get contents of different children using beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the location information for this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama_Institute_for_the_Deaf_and_Blind
that is located in the info box on the right of the page.

I've tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(site).text)
soup.find(('tr','adr').children
```

and

```
soup.find(('tr','adr').children.contents()
```

and

```
soup.find(('tr','adr').children.text
```

to no avail.

Comment: Did you mean to double up the `(` opening parenthesis there?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print just the `.text`:

```
>>> print soup.find('tr', 'adr').text

205 South St E
Talladega, Alabama, United States
```

You may want to remove the leading and trailing whitespace:

```
>>> soup.find('tr', 'adr').text.strip()
u'205 South St E\nTalladega, Alabama, United States'
>>> print soup.find('tr', 'adr').text.strip()
205 South St E
Talladega, Alabama, United States
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in soup.find_all('tr'):
        print i.text
```

That is a better way to get all of the tr's.